# Multiple WHERE clause in Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm new to LINQ and want to know how to execute multiple where clause. This is what I want to achieve: return records by filtering out certain user names. I tried the code below but not working as expected.

```
DataTable tempData = (DataTable)grdUsageRecords.DataSource;
var query = from r in tempData.AsEnumerable()
            where ((r.Field<string>("UserName") != "XXXX") || (r.Field<string>("UserName") != "XXXX"))                            
            select r;    

            DataTable newDT = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Well, you can just put multiple "where" clauses in directly, but I don't think you want to. Multiple "where" clauses ends up with a *more* restrictive filter - I think you want a *less* restrictive one. I think you really want:

```
DataTable tempData = (DataTable)grdUsageRecords.DataSource;
var query = from r in tempData.AsEnumerable()
            where r.Field<string>("UserName") != "XXXX" &&
                  r.Field<string>("UserName") != "YYYY"
            select r;

DataTable newDT = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Note the && instead of ||. You want to select the row if the username isn't XXXX *and* the username isn't YYYY.

EDIT: If you have a whole collection, it's even easier. Suppose the collection is called `ignoredUserNames`:

```
DataTable tempData = (DataTable)grdUsageRecords.DataSource;
var query = from r in tempData.AsEnumerable()
            where !ignoredUserNames.Contains(r.Field<string>("UserName"))
            select r;

DataTable newDT = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Ideally you'd want to make this a `HashSet<string>` to avoid the `Contains` call taking a long time, but if the collection is small enough it won't make much odds.

Comment: I have a UserName collection. How do I pass it to the where clause dynamically.

Comment: I know this was answered a long time ago but my quick suggestion would be to try and use join rather than contains. Is much more efficient (especially if your contains dataset is any reasonable size).

Comment: so if i have a use case where i have a predicate only on non null values, would it be better (readable) to have where(x => x.value!=null).where(y => y.value.Contains("someValue")).ToList() ? instead of .where(y => y.value!=null && y.value.Contains("someValue")).ToList()

Answer (score 52):

The LINQ translator is smart enough to execute:

```
.Where(r => r.UserName !="XXXX" && r.UsernName !="YYYY")
```

I've tested this in LinqPad
==> YES, Linq translator is smart enough :))

Comment: Smart enough means that Linq has extra filters which is a hit to performance.

Answer (score 7):

Also, you can use bool method(s)

Query :

```
DataTable tempData = (DataTable)grdUsageRecords.DataSource;
var query = from r in tempData.AsEnumerable()
            where isValid(Field<string>("UserName"))// && otherMethod() && otherMethod2()                           
            select r;   

        DataTable newDT = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Method:

```
bool isValid(string userName)
{
    if(userName == "XXXX" || userName == "YYYY")
        return false;
    else return true;
}
```