# how to select from two tables with two conditions in linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

i have two tables which has relation, i want to query from it with two conditions, like this:

```
var data = from d in db.table1
           where !d.isdeleted & d.table2.Where(dm => !dm.isdeleted)
           select d;
```

but i have this error:

> Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

thanx

Comment: &&    not & .......................

Comment: I think your question is directed related to that [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679644/multiple-where-clause-in-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're after?

```
var data = from d in db.table1
           where !d.isdeleted && d.table2.All(dm => !dm.isdeleted)
           select d;
```

This will select rows from `table1` where `isdeleted` is false and all the corresponding rows in `table2` have `isdeleted` equal to false.

Comment: thank you for answer
but the return data skip all column from table1 while table2 of any column has isdeleted equal to false

Answer (score 1):

If they are related, you could join the tables...

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ItemA> itemATable = new List<ItemA>(new[]
            {
                new ItemA {Id = "A1", IsDeleted = true},
                new ItemA {Id = "A2", IsDeleted = false},
            });

        List<ItemB> itemBTable = new List<ItemB>(new[]
            {
                new ItemB {Id = "B1", ItemAId = "A1", IsDeleted = true},
                new ItemB {Id = "B2", ItemAId = "A1", IsDeleted = false},
                new ItemB {Id = "B3", ItemAId = "A2", IsDeleted = true},
                new ItemB {Id = "B4", ItemAId = "A2", IsDeleted = false},
            });

        var test = from a in itemATable
                   join b in itemBTable on a.Id equals b.ItemAId
                   where !a.IsDeleted && !b.IsDeleted
                   select new { a, b };
    }
}

public class ItemA
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class ItemB
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemAId { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do two changes

1 . Change [`&` to `&&`](http://blog.dmbcllc.com/vs-and-vs-whats-the-difference) (this is not required, but a good practice until you want second operand to execute in all cases)

2 . Change `IEnumerable<T> (or IQueryable<T>)` to `bool`. Instead of `Where`, use `Any`

```
var data = from d in db.table1
       where !d.isdeleted && d.table2.Any(dm => !dm.isdeleted) 
       select d;
```