# LINQ where clause is being ignored

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am have an issue with a linq query. I am joining two tables but the where clauses are being completely ignored.

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
    var count = (from c in db.PERSON
                 join dt in db.DATA_INPUT_CHANGE_LOG
                      on c.DataInputTypeId equals dt.DataInputTypeId
                 join x in db.DATA_INPUT_CHANGE_LOG 
                      on c.Id equals x.DataItemId
                 where c.PersonId == p1Id &&
                  c.RefPersonId == p2Id && 
                  c.RelationshipId == rId
                 where x.Approved
                 where x.Checked
                 where x.Hidden == false
                 select c).Count();

    return count > 0;
}
```

In this particular query the `x.Approved`, `x.Checked` and `x.Hidden == false` where clauses are completely ignored.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679644/multiple-where-clause-in-linq
You probably want to specify where once

Comment: Have you run a profiler against your database to see exactly what sql is generated from that LINQ?

Comment: Why are you using multiple where's instead of just one and AND's?

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax is incorrect. You should only have one where clause. See below:

```
            var count = (from c in db.PERSON
                         join dt in db.DATA_INPUT_CHANGE_LOG
                              on c.DataInputTypeId equals dt.DataInputTypeId
                         join x in db.DATA_INPUT_CHANGE_LOG
                              on c.Id equals x.DataItemId
                         where c.PersonId == p1Id &&
                          c.RefPersonId == p2Id &&
                          c.RelationshipId == rId &&
                          x.Approved &&
                          x.Checked &&
                          x.Hidden == false
                         select c).Count();

            return count > 0;
```

Comment: The two options are equivalent.  There is nothing *wrong* with multiple `where` clauses.  They'll still work just fine.