# Multiple conditional where on list c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to add multiple conditional where on list but i can't

```
List<Account> accounts = getAccount();
```

and after on my liste i need to apply multiple condition like this how can i do it please beacause i can't make `And` on prdicate. This is my code

```
Func<Account, bool> predicate = X => true;

                if (request.id!= 0)
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(giftCard => giftCard.Id == request.Id);
                }
                if (request.code> 0)
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(giftCard => giftCard.code== request.code);
                    }
                if (request.cjn> 0)
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(giftCard => giftCard.cjn== request.cjn);
                    }
var resuly=accounts.where(predicate);
```

Comment: `var query = myList.Where(); if(x){ query=query.Where();}`. `List` is a container, it has no conditionals or filters. Querying is provided by LINQ

Comment: Just put conditions inside `Where` like this: `list.Where(item => item.Id == request.Id && item.Code == request.Code && ...)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/679644/109941

Comment: but i need to make them conditional that why i can put them inside the where

Comment: @DhouhaBenAchour: I see what confuses you. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Dennis, not covered by any of the "Linq conditional Where clause" question? Like [Linq: adding conditions to the where clause conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884651/)

Comment: Does that question has anything more than those chain of duplicate? Does it has better keyword? More searchable sentence? I see the word predicate in this question Perhaps it's related to [tag:predicatebuilder] and need a pointer to C# in deep article and related SO question. Or related to C# Predicate<T>.

Comment: @DragandDrop: your link mostly about `IQueryable` (I looked very quickly, so, maybe I'm wrong), and there are nuances between `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`. Anyway, the close reason in this case should be "Duplicate" with appropriate link. It's obvious that OP is newbie in C#, don't know why there are so many downvotes and wrong closing reason (IMO, it's clear what OP wants to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [linqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) for this scenario.
It has that exact And() function you used in your sample code.

[image]